# error in deleting an item from listview

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application in which i have a static listview which contains 5 items.

I want that when i click on selected item an alert dialog should appear containing buttons yes or no. If i click on yes, selected item should get deleted.

Is it possible? If yes, how? Can anyone guide me.The data in the list is static

Here is my java class code

http://pastebin.com/AMJy9cBH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call adapter.clear() followed by adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() when you want to delete the elements.

Comment: That is going to remove all the elements from the list

Comment: Check this out Shailendra: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#clear%28%29

Comment: use public void remove (T object) in your case  remove(title[position])

Answer (score 2):

```
    ArrayList<String> sampleList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> sampleListArrayAdapter;

    ListView sampleListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sampleListView);

    sampleListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            SampleActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Do you want delete this item?");
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        // On clicking "Yes" button
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            sampleList.remove(position);

            sampleListArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });

        // On clicking "No" button
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel(); // Cancel dialog
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Thanks,,In the alert dialog creation i should put ur code ??

Comment: @AMMY,,when i add your code into main java class...Its giving errors,,,,

Answer (score 0):

Remove the item from the data list and notify the list adapter about the change.

```
data.remove(Item);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Alert dialog tutorial is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

Answer (score 0):

When the user chooses to delete the row, get the row number where user wanted this deletion to happen, refer to the corresponding element of your source array, remove that element and then call `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`